# Which version of jQuery is supported by Google Apps Script?

Tags: jquery, google-apps-script

My script runs fine when using jQuery in HTMLService in version 1.8.3 ...

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

...but it fails with the latest

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I've searched for info on the help pages but cannot find which versions are supported.

Comment: This might be an issue to report on the issue tracker:  [Apps Script Issues](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/)

Answer (score 3):

Third party libraries go through a Caja sanitization so everytime a new version of jQuery is released there can be some problem.
Right now the newest working jquery version is 1.11.0

You can do your test on http://caja.appspot.com/ with a code like this

```
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( document ).ready(function() {
      $("span").text("Working");
    });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <span>Not Working</span>
  </body>
</html>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

If you'll try to "Cajole" this code you'll see "Working" in the "Rendered Result" tab otherwise a sad "Not Working" would be showned.
Try to change the version of jquery and made your test.

**UPDATE**: Now 1.11.1 it's working

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quote from the documentation:

### jQuery and jQuery UI

> All recent versions of the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries are
>   compatible with Caja, but the libraries load faster if you use the
>   versions that Google hosts:

```
 jQuery: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 jQuery UI: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

[jQuery Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#jquery_and_jquery_ui)

Comment: It may validate that it should.  And knowing that may help narrow down what steps to take next.  They didn't ask why it doesn't work with 1.1.  The question is which versions are supported.

Comment: What I meant is, this answer says it should work, but it doesnt. But I guess that belongs to the gas bug tracker :)

Comment: Oh. :) Okay.  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

**Only the jQuery/jQuery UI versions *listed in Caja's source* are REALLY compatible with Google Apps Scripts** (look at the `jquery` and `jqueryui` nodes):
https://code.google.com/p/google-caja/source/browse/#svn%2Fbranches%2Fes53%2Fthird_party%2Fprecajole%2Fjquery

---

So the Google documentation itself states something that is simply **NOT TRUE**:
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/restrictions#jquery_and_jquery_ui

> *jQuery and jQuery UI*
>
> ***All recent versions of the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries are compatible with Caja [...]***

But the truth is that currently it's NOT compatible with the most recent jQuery (2.1.3) and jQuery UI (1.11.2) version.

So you should look at the list linked above for the appropriate jQuery (UI) version(s) if you get an *"`Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function`"* error message on the console ([like this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qt4CH.png)).

There's a related post in this issue thread:
https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=4311#c1

> *"I've found the underlying Caja compiler to be incompatible with certain versions of the jQuery/UI libraries.
>
>   Presently I'm using jQuery 2.1.0 & jQueryUI 1.11.0 successfully in a project, but if I > attempt to load the latest jQuery 2.1.1, the console throws numerous errors at me.
>
>   Generally you can find out which versions of jQuery and the Caja compiler are compatible by looking at Caja's source:
>
>   http://goo.gl/rzIz2y"*